# The screen flickering is back on the 2nd boot and boot time is longer after updating grub. Why?

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2

I edited grub and removed splash, added noresume as suggested elsewhere then updated grub. The first boot is always without flickering and the boot time is normal. (I have a Dell Inspiron 3670 with an integrated Intel graphic card and Intel core i3 8th gen and no dual boot)

I ran this experiment: sudo update-grub without making any change to the grub file. I shut down the pc and restarted. There was no flickering and the boot time is again normal (a bit more than  60s).

Does the fact that the flickering comes back after the 1st boot and the boot takes longer (2 minutes and sometimes more) means that some other file needs to be updated? If it's the case, which file? And how do I update it?

Please, if you suggest a solution, please provide the full command.

Answer (score 0):

For few weeks, I read just about every post on screen flickering and whenever possible tried the suggested solution or suggestion. Nothing worked. However, when I run systemd-analyze time, I was getting normal boot times. The only problem was the consistent delay of more than 2 minutes in getting to the desktop.

So I decided to test the monitor by itself and not connected to the same power bar as the pc. When I did that, I saw the flickering of the screen before I turned on the computer. And the flickering would stop after about one minute and half to 2 mn. This told me that my monitor was basically coming to the end of its useful life.

I should have started the debugging of the screen flickering by testing the monitor itself, I would have avoided a lot of frustration.